# No computers on my network can access my website

Tags: networking, router, dns

I'm stumped by this one!

My website : https://www.genyx.co.uk/business/

Will not load on my PC, iPhone, Netbook or any other computers connected to my network (Virgin 100MB)

The website loads for anyone else (try it) but not me!

I've tried flushing the dns, clearing the cache but nothing works, and it can't be my pc since it doesn't work on any of my devices.

I have tried resetting the router, but it doesn't work.
I tried ringing virgin and they said they will fix it for £60....

```
C:\Users\Adam>ping genyx.co.uk
Ping request could not find host genyx.co.uk. Please check the name and try agai
n.

C:\Users\Adam>tracert genyx.co.uk
Unable to resolve target system name genyx.co.uk.
```

I can access any other website just fine!

Now recent history, last night my domain host (EUKHOST, who are useless) decided it would be really funny to reset the nameservers, so the website didn't load for anyone. I changed them back and now the website loads for everyone except me!

I though maybe the dns settings had been cached somewhere? Maybe in the router (Virgin Super Hub) but I don't know how to clear that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is possible that the DNS is still propagating if it was only reset yesterday. Some ISP's are notoriously slow (I have heard of waiting times of up to 72 hours to access some websites - not great if you're a business!)

Alternatively...I had a similar problem with all of my websites on my dedicated server a few years ago. It turned out that it was my server blocking my IP due to excessive FTP requests etc. All I did was add an exception for my IP.

Perhaps it's worth contacting your host to check your IP hasn't been blacklisted?

Comment: Thats an interesting thought, although I can access the website by using the IP address, so I am assuming it is a DNS issue.
Looks like I'll just have to wait until tomorrow to see if it works :(

Comment: If you can access via IP, then it is certainly a DNS issue. it might not necessarily be your ISP - it's also possible that your DNS zones are not configured correctly, which would lead to some people being able to access the site and others not. I'd wait another day though before you take it any further.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll report back tomorrow. Just if anyone orders anything today, I won't be able to process them!

Comment: You can probably still access your email via the IP, or your order system as well. You could also always just purchase vpn or proxy access for a day if you need to!

Comment: What's interesting, is that I cannot receive any mail, BUT outlook doesn't throw any errors, it just says 'Success'

Comment: The website is now back for me, looks like it was just a propagation issue, thanks.

Comment: It does not work here! (Germany, ISP KabelDeutschland) EDIT: Yes, it does. It just took like 20 seconds to load the page.

Comment: Was that because the server was slow or the DNS took ages to respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Checking registration details

You can use the `whois` service run by a number of registrars to check registration details for your domain. For .co.uk domains the authoritative registrar is Nominet.

It looks like your domain registration details were recently updated

[Nominet](http://www.nominet.org.uk/other/whois/) say the registration was last updated today.

The registration info has not yet propagated elsewhere e.g. http://www.whois.net/whois/genyx.co.uk currently says this domain is "available"

*Update, [Whois.com](http://www.whois.com/whois/genyx.co.uk) does show the correct details - perhaps there is just a problem at whois.net.*

### Checking DNS service

I would use a tool such as `nslookup` or `dig` or `host` (depending on Operating System) to check the DNS records at various places - including your local ISP's DNS servers.

The DNS servers for eUKhost.com know about your domain

```
C:\> nslookup genyx.co.uk dns1.stabletransit.com
Server:  ns.rackspace.com
Address:  69.20.95.4

Name:    genyx.co.uk
Address:  31.222.190.239
```

But other DNS servers don't (yet)

```
C:\> nslookup genyx.co.uk
Server:  api.home
Address:  192.168.1.254

*** api.home can't find genyx.co.uk: Server failed
```

*Update, I can now resolve your domain's IP-address using nslookup at another location.*

Comment: That is really confusing, especially since I registered it about a year ago and expires in 2014.
No-one can purchase it can they?

Comment: The domain was NOT recently renewed. Last updated just means the changes to the DNS or registration info. As you can see it is a January renewal, not a July one.

Comment: Answer updated to clarify

Comment: The website is now back for me, looks like it was just a propagation issue, thanks.